# Remove Array junk from result - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Looking on how to remove useless junk from result like:

```
] => Array ( [] =>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=planes+seen+from+dallas&appid=2UJ62E-Q6RT3T89P8';

$parser = new XMLReader;
$parser->open($url);

while ($parser->read()) {
    if ($parser->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT) {

        while ($parser->name === 'pod' && $parser->getAttribute('title') !== 'Result')
            $parser->next('pod'); // jump to the next pod node 

        if ($parser->name === 'plaintext') {
            $str = $parser->readString();
            $parser->close();    
            break;
        }
    }
}

$lines = explode("\n", $str);
$result = array();

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $fields = explode(' | ', $line);
    $flight = array_shift($fields);
    $flight = $flight . "<hr>"; //DELETE IF DOESN'T WORK

    if ($flight === '')
        $cols = $fields;
    elseif (isset($fields[1])) {
        $result[$flight][$cols[0]] = $fields[0];
        $result[$flight][$cols[1]] = $fields[1];
    } 
}

print_r($result);
?>
```

Sample output:

`Array ( [] => Array ( [] => slant distance ) [Atlantic Southeast Airlines flight 5520`
`] => Array ( [] => 23 miles SW ) [Volaris flight 940`
`] => Array ( [] => 30 miles NNW ) [American Airlines flight 386`
`] => Array ( [] => 14 miles NW ) [American Airlines flight 296`
`] => Array ( [] => 27 miles W ) [Central Air Southwest flight 7] => Array ( [] => 6.5 miles WSW ) )`

At each break, there's a `<hr>` tag, not very important though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this:
      <?php
    $url = 'http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=planes+seen+from+dallas&appid=2UJ62E-Q6RT3T89P8';

    $parser = new XMLReader;
    $parser->open($url);

    while ($parser->read()) {
        if ($parser->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT) {

            while ($parser->name === 'pod' && $parser->getAttribute('title') !== 'Result')
                $parser->next('pod'); // jump to the next pod node 

            if ($parser->name === 'plaintext') {
                $str = $parser->readString();
                $parser->close();    
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $lines = explode("\n", $str);
    $result = array();

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $fields = explode(' | ', $line);
        $flight = array_shift($fields);
        $flight = $flight . "<hr>"; //DELETE IF DOESN'T WORK

        if ($flight === '')
            $cols = $fields;
        elseif (isset($fields[1])) {
            $result[$flight][$cols[0]] = $fields[0];
            $result[$flight][$cols[1]] = $fields[1];
        } 
    }

    foreach($result as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo $key;
        foreach($value as $value1){

        echo $value1;
echo " &nbsp;";
}
    }
```